# Determine action on process kill in Windows

Tags: c#, windows

Let's assume that we have got simple program like below. Is it even possible to make some action on unexpected quit of the program?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

}

public void onKillDoSomething()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: There is no way to get notified about a forceful process kill.  Never a real problem, no notification either when somebody trips over the power cord and unplugs it.

Comment: You mean killed due to an unhandled exception in your code or because someone does a `taskkill` of your process?

Comment: unhandled exception? Yes, appdomain.unhandledexception. Task manager kill? No.

Comment: Eh, you could use Process.Exit to catch most situations... Otherwise, however, you'll have to resort to timers to check if it's still alive I think.